# Does ImageIO.read() always return BufferedImage with transparency?

Tags: java, image, transparency, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

The title explains it all.
Lets say i have the following code:

```
BufferedImage image;
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Would image's type always be `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` or other type with an alpha channel? (I am using Java 8 btw)

Comment: In theory it should only return a image with transparency if the image supports transparency, but that would come down to the plugin that was used to load the image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my testing, it appears that the BufferedImage adapts to what image you have.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;

public class BufferedImageTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedImage transparent = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png"));
            System.out.println(transparent.getType());
            BufferedImage solid = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://blacklabelsociety.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/spacer.jpg"));
            System.out.println(solid.getType());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
6
5
```

6 = BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR

5 = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR

The first image had transparency, whereas the second one did not.

Comment: This would be depended upon the implementation of the plugin and could change between JVMs or based on what the user has installed.

Comment: The main thing was that the bufferedimage adapts, not what it adapts to. :)

Comment: Not really, the `BufferedImage` is a result of it's creation.  You could easily load a non-transparent image into a `BufferedImage` that won't change it's type...

Comment: It goes in context with the question, based on what code he provided, it would adapt.

Comment: But it's not the `BufferedImage` which is adapting, it's how the plugin which is used to load that type of image which is deciding what type of `BufferedImage` to create.  Therefore, change the plugin, change the result...

Comment: I think my issue is *"Would image's type **always** be"* which can't be guaranteed...

Comment: Hm I guess you're right. I just decided to put in my two cents anyway.

Comment: Your observations aren't wrong, you just can't guarantee them ;)

Comment: I like your broad way of thinking, I might have to learn to think like you :P

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. Not always. It can be any type.

Longer answer:
`ImageIO.read(...)` should only return an image type with alpha, if the image read has an alpha channel, but as @MadProgrammer says in his comment, this is really plugin-specific. Most `ImageReader` plugins that I know of, will return the most "natural" type for the input, that is the one that is closest to the native format of the input file.

It is however possible to specify the type of image you want, or even specify the target image to load into. To do this, you need to obtain an `ImageReader` instance for the format you want to read, and pass the type or image to the `setDestination(...)` or `setDestinationType(...)` methods on the `ImageReadParam`.